# How can I abstract mysqli prepared statements in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, prepared-statement

I'm using my own class for database queries, extending mysqli:

```
class iDatabase extends mysqli
{
    public  $errorMsg;
    private $totalQueries;
    private $stmt;

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct( 'localhost', 'asd', 'asd', 'asd' );

        if ( mysqli_connect_errno() )
        {
            $this->errorMsg = 'Could not connect to server.<br /><i>' . mysqli_connect_error() . '</i>.';
            return;
        }

        parent::query( 'SET NAMES utf8' );
    }

}
```

However I'm running into trouble when executing queries and getting back results. I'm using prepared statements, but the way values and results are bound is confusing me. After a bit of research I came up with this function that accepts the query and parameters:

```
public function psQuery( $query, $params )
{
    $this->stmt = parent::prepare( $query );
    call_user_func_array( array($this->stmt,'bind_param'), $params );
    $this->stmt->execute();
}
```

My question is, what is the best way to get results back from this? I need to use bind_result, then fetch each row, then close the statement. I'd prefer to just get an associative array for each row - is that possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I worked on the `Zend_Db_Adapter_Mysqli` and `Zend_Db_Statement_Mysqli` classes quite a bit to get this to work, since we wanted to make it conform to the `PDO` and `PDOStatement` interface.  It was pretty laborious, because of the confusing way MySQLi insists on making you bind variables to get results, and the variety of fetch modes supported by `PDOStatement`.

If you want to see the code in `Zend_Db`, pay special attention to the functions
`Zend_Db_Statement_Mysqli::_execute()` and `fetch()`.  Basically, the `_execute()` method binds an array of variable references using `call_user_func_array()`.  The tricky part is that you have to initialize the array so the `bind_result()` function gets the references.  Uh, that wasn't totally clear, so go take a look at the code.

Or else just use PDO's MySQL driver.  That's what I would do in your shoes.

Comment: Where would I find the code? I looked here but it's only documentation, no code: http://framework.zend.com/apidoc/core/Zend_Db/Statement/Zend_Db_Statement_Mysqli.html

Comment: @DisgruntledGoat: You can download it, of course, or else you can browse the source online at http://framework.zend.com/code/browse/Standard_Library/standard/trunk/library/Zend

Comment: I decided to take your last piece of advice and use PDO. Seems a lot simpler!

Comment: Yes, for the usage you're trying to implement, it's much easier.  The `execute()` method already accepts an array of parameters, there's no binding to be done.

Answer (score 1):

I would take a look at the implementation of [Zend_Db](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.html), in particular the [mysqli adapter](http://framework.zend.com/wiki/display/ZFUSER/Zend_Db+Adapters+Overview), to see how they're doing it.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have to do what you said "I need to use bind_result, then fetch each row, then close the statement"

I think there is no simpler way.